# Getting Outlook profile image in Vue as v-img src

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, outlook

I am trying to create a profile image that changes, depending on who is logged in so I cannot hardcode the email into the url

how would i go about this

html

```html
<v-avatar size="128" absolute color="secondary">
    <v-img:src="`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users${email}/photo/$value`" />
</v-avatar>
```

computed

```js
email() {
    return this.staffMember.WorkEmail
},
```

Email is returned as devan@bsuregroup.co.za
but no image is being displayed

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/photo-rest-operations#get-photo) URL you need to query for photo looks like this:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('{user_id}')/photo/$value
```

You need to change your URL in the `v-img` element:

```
<v-avatar size="128" absolute color="secondary">
    <v-img:src="`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(${email})/photo/$value`" />
</v-avatar>
```